# How can a status bar be displayed on Windows 8 and Windows 10 desktop login screen programmatically?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, authentication

I am facing these problem:

Our computers in our network perform a patch managment each day. These takes several minutes. Is it possible to show the status bar of these patching process on the login screen of all our computers? They are running on Windows 8 and 10. It would be cool, if that would be possible to do this in C# or C++.
I only found post saying that maybe a GINA dll must be rewritten. Most post do say that that is not possible.

I don't want the screen to be locked, so login should still be possible, while displaying the status bar.
I do know that by changing a Reg. Key you can change the wallpaper, but that is not what I am looking for.

Any help would be great.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for https://stackoverflow.com, this question should be posted to https://superuser.com/

Comment: ... unless you are asking how to do it programmatically?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this isnt a superuser question at all...

Answer (score 2):

For customizing the Windows login screen, you need to use [Credential Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-and-credential-providers) which are meant to provide custom login options (e.g. an extra button for smartcard authentication).

You could use this API to create a "hidden" Credential Provider (i.e. one that doesnt show any logon-related UI) and have it [spawn a window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window) with the progress bar upon it's initialization.

A full sample implementation of a credential provder can be found in the Windows SDK in the `\Samples\Security\CredentialProvider` folder.